# extract email id using regex

Tags: controller

How can i get the third email id (lightuser@abc.co.uk)from the below text using regex.

Please share if you have any idea.

**Example Text:**

Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:

setupuser@abc.co.uk

apuser@abc.co.uk

lightuser@abc.co.uk

A problem occurred during the delivery of this message to this e-mail address. Try sending this message again.

Comment: The error is apparently misleading--all three emails were not delivered.

Comment: yeah but i wanted the third email address alone.

Comment: Yes, I can give you a regex to get you *exactly* that, but are you asking for, *the last email* or *the third email*?

Comment: Third email alone..

Comment: i have another example, <br/> if i forward a bounced email to Email service address like below, it should exclude the from and two address from the body and should extract the email id which is under "Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:" <br/>

Comment: Thanks,
abcUser
________________________________
From: saastest
Sent: Monday, March 5, 2018 10:41 PM
To: demo@2.apex.sandbox.salesforce.com
Subject: Fw: Undeliverable: Sandbox: Modified email addressTODAY2



Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:

abc@apple.co.uk<mailto:abc@apple.co.uk>


<br/>A problem occurred during the delivery of this message to this e-mail address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specifically match the third email you encounter, you could use a pattern like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(?s)(mailto:)?(\\S+@\\S+).*?(mailto:)?(\\S+@\\S+).*?(mailto:)?(\\S+@\\S+).*');
Matcher m = p.matcher(sourceString);
if(m.find()) {
  System.debug('Third email found: '+m.group(6));
}
```

Where:

- `(?s)` allows `.` to match newlines by setting the DOTALL flag.
- `(mailto:)?` strips out an optional mailto: prefix (as in your comment example)
- `(\\S+@\\S+)` matches a string of non-spaces, the `@` symbol, and more non-spaces.
- `.*?` is a non-greedy match of all characters, including newlines.
- `(...)` in general are "capture groups", except the first, which is a flag setting.
- `m.find()` returns true if there's a match, allowing us to get the results gia `group`.
- `m.group(6)` grabs the sixth capture group.

Note that this is a very specific solution that may not always work in all situations, but will work just fine as long as there's no unexpected email-looking constructs anywhere before the third email.